# Working with two different sensors data at the same time in android

Tags: android, android-service, android-sensors

I'm trying to make a sensor based audio profile manager where it takes values from ACCELEROMETER & LIGHT sensor, then determines conditions and switch profiles according to conditions. I was able to work with single sensor but cannot make it work with two. Here is my code,

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    boolean isOn = false;
    boolean isFlipped = false;
    boolean isFront = false;
    boolean isOnPocket = false;
    Sensor mySensor = event.sensor;
    long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {
        float light = event.values[0];

        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
            lastUpdate = curTime;

            if (light<=100) {
                isOn = true;
            }else{
                isOn = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];

        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
            lastUpdate = curTime;

            if (x<=0 && y<=0 && z<=-10) {
                isFlipped=true;
            }else if (x<=0 && y<=0 && z<=+9){
                isFront=true;
            }else if (x<=2 && y<=-7 && z<=-1){
                isOnPocket=true;
            }
        }
    }

    if(isFlipped && isOn){
        myAudManHolder.silent();
    }else if(isFront && !isOn){
        myAudManHolder.ring();
    }else if(isOnPocket && isOn){
        myAudManHolder.vibrate();
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong in my code? I need help badly. Your help would be appreciable. Tnx.

Comment: what you get in `mySensor.getType() ` ?

Comment: I don't know how to check that.

Comment: debug and check the value you get in `mySensor.getType()`

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I'm new to android. Kindly can you tell me how to debug?

Comment: have a [look here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDebugging/article.html)

Comment: I launched my app in debugging mode but where to see `mySensor.getType()` value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67366/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-sin-oscuras).